# Android avd tombstone disabled

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, crash-reports

after causing an app crash on the avd (virtual device emulation in adt), i've checked the /data/tombstones folder but it does not exist. 
Using the same avd on another computer the crash generates the tombstone file in /data/tombstones. 
Why mine does not create the crash report? There is some config file or setting i have to check?
Thank's all